# Appending rig with constraints and drivers

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers, append

i appended a rig from one blend file to current working one. the rig is transferred but the constraints are no more there and neither the drivers. How i transfer the constraints and drivers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to blender myself, i solved it, you need to select the armature in the object folder (not in the armature folder) and then append it

Answer (score 0):

I'm relative new to Blender rigging. I have successfully appended 2.81 generation custom character rig with many constraints and drivers into 2.93.

I made sure to rename/ make the rig as a collection in 2.8 Blender (which I haven't uninstalled). Like, Mary Rig Collection.

Then I append the (clearly named and easily identified) COLLECTION into 2.93.

Usually there's no drama, just need to disable/ hide custom bones. Drivers will work, constraints are all there.

After double-checking everything, I re-save a new 2.93 Rig Collection blend file of this character.

Good luck.

Comment: I am new to blender myself, i solved it, you need to select the armature in the object folder (not in the armature folder) and then append it.